# Mounting GPT partition table in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, gpt

I have a drive that I'm trying to mount in linux.   The device is /dev/xvdf.  `lsblk` shows two subdrives, /dev/xvdf1 and /dev/xvdf9

`sudo file -s /dev/xvdf` tells me that /dev/xvdf is a "GPT partition table".  /dev/xvdf1 and /dev/xvdf9 are just "data"

When I try to mount /dev/xvdf, I get an error about a missing superblock.

When I try to mount /dev/xvdf1, I get the error:

> mount: unknown filesystem type 'zfs_member'

How do I mount this drive?

Answer (score 1):

First, run

```
sudo zpool import
```

This will tell you the name of the pool.  You can then import it via

```
sudo zpool import [poolname]
```

Then running mount on /dev/xvdf works fine.